# ReferenceError and undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm a bit confused by this js behavior.

```
function foo(){
  console.log(a)
}

foo() // ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

In this case everything is understandable. There is no `a` defined in the global scope, therefore we get the  `ReferenceError`.

Now, this is a second example:

```
function foo(){
  console.log(this.a)
}

foo() // undefined
```

So, `this` points to the global scope where there is no `a` defined. Shouldn't we get the same `ReferenceError` ?  Why do we get `undefined` ?

Comment: It doesn't point to the global scope, it points to the global *object*, and property accesses of unknown keys return `undefined`. For instance `({}).a === undefined`.

Comment: @JaredSmith ohh i got it now, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically `Reference error` will come when you use a variable which are not `declared` yet, whereas `undefined` will come when you try to get some properties from the object and key is not present in an object, or you make a variable itself undefined

Ex.

**undefined**

```js
  const obj = { };
  const array = [];
  const newObj = undefined;

  console.log(obj.id);// undefined
  console.log(newObj);// undefined
  console.log(array[0]);// undefined
```

**Reference Error**

```js
 const obj = { };
 console.log(obj[id] = id);
```

> **Note** `this` is also an `object`, In your case you try to access value of `a` from `this`

So it's looks like

```
const this = {};
console.log(this.a) // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is logical and that's what should happen. In the first example, you referenced a variable and that variable isn't declared so you get a `ReferenceError` but in the second example, you called an `object` (`this === window` in that case) attribute named `a` which is `undefined`. If you want to also get errors even for `undefined` members (`object`s attributes), you could use `use strict` at the beginning of your function (or the file).

```js
/** here we get undefined **/
(function() {
  console.log(this.a);
})();

/** but here we get something like "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined" as we used "use strict" at the begining of the IIFE **/
(function() {
  'use strict';
  console.log(this.a);
})();
```